# angular injector with asp.net Boilerplate not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to use the Angular injection come with asp.net Boilerplate,
I'm following the "tutorial" from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791740/Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram#ArticleBuildWebApiServices

to get started with my project, for now I want to load the Tasks as Parts

but for some reason I get the following error:

`Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=os.views.part.list&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Nb (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:19:417)
    at ob (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:1)
    at $get (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:75:177)
    at http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:57:112
    at r (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at I (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:56:496)
    at g (http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at http://localhost:6234/Scripts/angular.min.js:50:414`

the application is a SPA.

the Main app is loaded here:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("app", [
        "ngAnimate",
        "ngSanitize",
        "ui.router",
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "ui.jq",
        "abp"
    ]);

    //Configuration for Angular UI routing.
    app.config([
        "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/home/home.cshtml",
                    menu: "Home" //Matches to name of 'Home' menu in OnderdelenshopNavigationProvider
                })
                .state("about", {
                    url: "/about",
                    templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/about/about.cshtml",
                    menu: "About" //Matches to name of 'About' menu in OnderdelenshopNavigationProvider
                })
                .state("listParts", {
                    url: "/list",
                    templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/parts/list.cshtml",
                    menu: "ListParts"
                });
        }
    ]);
})();
```

then when routed to /list the following JS is loaded:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("app");

    var controllerId = "os.views.parts.list";

    app.controller(controllerId, [
        '$scope', 'abp.services.tasksystem.part',
        function($scope, partService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.localize = abp.localization.getSource("Onderdelenshop");

            vm.parts = [];

            $scope.selectedTaskState = 0;

            $scope.$watch("selectedPartState", function(value) {
                vm.refreshParts();
            });

            vm.refreshParts = function () {
                console.log("test");

                abp.ui.setBusy( //Set whole page busy until getTasks complete
                    null,
                    partService.getParts({ //Call application service method directly from javascript
                        state: $scope.selectedPartState > 0 ? $scope.selectedPartState : null
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        console.log("hey");
                        vm.parts = data.parts;
                    })
                );
            };

            vm.changePartState = function(part) {
                var newState;
                if (part.state === 1) {
                    newState = 2; //Completed
                } else {
                    newState = 1; //Active
                }

                partService.updatePart({
                    partId: part.id,
                    state: newState
                }).success(function() {
                    part.state = newState;
                    abp.notify.info(vm.localize("TaskUpdatedMessage"));
                });
            };

            vm.getPartCountText = function() {
                return abp.utils.formatString(vm.localize("Xparts"), vm.parts.length);
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

this is the `http://localhost:6234/api/AbpServiceProxies/GetAll?type=angular`

```
(function (abp, angular) {

    if (!angular) {
        return;
    }

    var abpModule = angular.module('abp');

    abpModule.factory('abp.services.tasksystem.person', [
        '$http', function ($http) {
            return new function () {
                this.getAllPeople = function (httpParams) {
                    return $http(angular.extend({
                        abp: true,
                        url: abp.appPath + 'api/services/tasksystem/person/GetAllPeople',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify({})
                    }, httpParams));
                };

            };
        }
    ]);


})((abp || (abp = {})), (angular || undefined));


(function (abp, angular) {

    if (!angular) {
        return;
    }

    var abpModule = angular.module('abp');

    abpModule.factory('abp.services.tasksystem.task', [
        '$http', function ($http) {
            return new function () {
                this.getTasks = function (input, httpParams) {
                    return $http(angular.extend({
                        abp: true,
                        url: abp.appPath + 'api/services/tasksystem/task/GetTasks',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(input)
                    }, httpParams));
                };

                this.updateTask = function (input, httpParams) {
                    return $http(angular.extend({
                        abp: true,
                        url: abp.appPath + 'api/services/tasksystem/task/UpdateTask',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(input)
                    }, httpParams));
                };

                this.createTask = function (input, httpParams) {
                    return $http(angular.extend({
                        abp: true,
                        url: abp.appPath + 'api/services/tasksystem/task/CreateTask',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(input)
                    }, httpParams));
                };

            };
        }
    ]);


})((abp || (abp = {})), (angular || undefined));
```

Any ideas what I might be forgetting?

**Update 1:** Got further; the controller definition must be like this:

```
app.controller(controllerId, [
        '$scope', '$location', 'abp.services.tasksystem.part',
        function ($scope, $location, partService) { ... }
```

Now getting internal error though, trying to fix that

Comment: Change this line var app = angular.module("app"); to var app = angular.module("app", []); and try!! Square brackets needed there for registering your app

Comment: @Asik That is loaded in the app.js (updated the question)

Comment: ok fine..I have seen your update..seems you have corrected registering controller syntax as per Agular 1.3 way

Answer (score -1):

I was wondering where are you getting the abp in the controller. You need to inject it

Comment: not fully sure on that part, it get's loaded automaticly by my understanding, it defenitly works because I can load from my other service to get all persons